# How to configure the 'smtp ' settings on docker/redmine container instance?

Tags: email, docker, smtp, redmine

Install & run steps:

1. docker pull redmine:latest // 3.3.3
2. docker run -d -p 10030:3000 -v /opt/yunpan01/redmine:/usr/src/redmine --name redmine redmine:latest

redmine started successfully.

But the smtp settings was not Configured.

Please tell me how to configure the SMTP settings.

Comment: See if this can help - https://github.com/namshi/docker-smtp

Answer (score 8):

You can modify configuration.yml by two ways:
 **1. use command**
 `docker cp FILEPATH_IN_YOUR_HOST CONTAINER_ID:PATH_IN_YOUR_CONTAINER`
 eg. `vi configuration.yml`, then type in these codes:

```
 default:
      email_delivery:
        delivery_method: :smtp
        smtp_settings:
          address: "smtp.yourcompany.com"
          port: 25
```

then `docker cp configuration.yml redmine:/usr/src/redmine/config/configuration.yml`
**2. volumns**
mapping the container's directory to your host path

```
docker run -d -p 10030:3000 -v /opt/yunpan01/redmine:/usr/src/redmine/files --name redmine redmine:latest
vi /opt/yunpan01/redmine/configuration.yml
```

same step as above to key in the configuration.yml

```
  default:
      email_delivery:
        delivery_method: :smtp
        smtp_settings:
          address: "smtp.yourcompany.com"
          port: 25
```

now you can make a file link in container

```
docker exec redmine ln -s \
/usr/src/redmine/files/configuration.yml\
 /usr/src/redmine/config/configuration.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that redmine official image do not provide this kind of configurations.

You may want to try [sameersbn/redmine](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine) or [bitnami/redmine](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter into container by 
   sudo docker exec -i -t 
   /bin/bash
2. copy or rename /usr/src/redmine/config/configuration.yml.example in  /usr/src/redmine/config/configuration.yml
3. map this file in a volume
   redmine:
      image: redmine
      ports:
       - "8089:3000"
      volumes:
       - '/home/ubuntu/docker/redmine/allfiles:/usr/src/redmine/files'
       **- '/home/ubuntu/docker/redmine/configuration.yml:/usr/src/redmine/config/configuration.yml'**
4. Set email configuration on this file, as explained [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration)

Comment: You will lose configuration if you recreate the cointainer! Configuration HAS to be persistent in a volume or in a mounted file!

Answer (score -1):

You have to enter your smtp settings in the configuration.yml file.

See this link: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration